# How to check repeatedly for condition

Tags: c#, windows, forms, media

Some time ago, I asked a question about playing .mp3 files in C# program. As the answers were really helpful, I decided to ask for other question again here. I have a code:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

if (wplayer.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
{
     *something to do...*
}
else
{
}
```

Between the brackets for "else" I need to learn my program something like: "When playstate change come back to this if condition"(which basically means to say him: "Only if playstate change to "media ended" do what i write in *something to do*") So this is my question. How to do that? Is there any command for "check value" or something which will help me? Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at full documentation on [PlayStateChange event supported by WindowsMediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstatechange)

In case you don't know what the `event` in C# is:

Events serve the purpose you described - they notify when something happens (the moment when and why this *something* happens is defined by class developers). In our case, `WindowsMediaPlayer` has an event `PlayStateChange`, which is triggered when play state of the object changes.

So now, even though the player changes its state and the event is triggered by the class, we'll never know about it, since we never subscribed for receiving a notification from the event.

To do so, you write your own function (which is conventionally called a *handler*). This function should have a particular signature - it should return `void` and accept two arguments: first of a type `object` (which you can convert to WindowsMediaPlayer type, because this type is the source of our event) and the second of some type with supplementary data of event)

An example is straight from the link above:

```
private void player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
   // this code is executed when the playstate changed
   // no need to check - developers of the WindowsMediaPlayer class
   // tell you, that it happened, by calling this function
   // they even give you some data about this changed state via arguments (sender and e above)

   // Test the current state of the player and display a message for each state.
   switch (e.newState)
   {
        case 0:    // Undefined
            currentStateLabel.Text = "Undefined";
            break;

        case 1:    // Stopped
            currentStateLabel.Text = "Stopped";
            break;
        ... // check the link for more states
   }
}
```

Next you have to subscribe this freshly written function for the event. So when the play state is changed, the class of player will call our function:

```
// Add a delegate for the PlayStateChange event.
player.PlayStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(player_PlayStateChange);
```

So basically, you have the function `player_PlayStateChange` accepting two arguments about the event, and this function is called when `PlayStateChange` event of `player` object is triggered. The confusing `AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler` is a class, that just wraps our function, you can attach a function only after wrapping it.

I encourage you to learn more about events and delegates in C# on more simple and understandable examples or tutorials. The concept of events is crucial for programming.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I will definitely have a look on "Events" to understand the examples about correctly.